# Change /proc/asound/cards name

Tags: alsa

I have two identical USB sound cards. /proc/asound/cards shows them as:

```
2 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB Audio Device
GeneralPlus USB Audio Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed
3 [Device_1       ]: USB-Audio - USB Audio Device
GeneralPlus USB Audio Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed
```

The problem is that applications list them both as "USB Audio Device" and when selecting the second occurrence, the application uses the first.

Is there any way of changing the "USB Audio Device" name?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds card names are not unique; this is a bug in that application.

Only the card ID (here: "Device(_1)") is guaranteed to be unique, and only the ID can be changed (see "Identify two identical audio devices" on [this wiki page](https://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev)).

The card name is whatever the USB device reports as its name, and cannot be modified (except by changing the kernel driver).